# Why does my minute wont change if seconds == 60

Tags: ios, swift

So im working with a countdown watch with minute and seconds and slider to change its value. I want to make my minute to add 1 if seconds == 60. But it wont work. Please help.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

var seconds = 59
var minute = 0

@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var sliderOutlet: UISlider!
@IBAction func slider(sender: UISlider) {

    seconds = Int(sender.value)

    minute = Int(sender.value)


    if seconds == 60 {

        minute = minute + 1
        seconds = 0

    }



    label.text = String(minute) + " Minute :" + String(seconds) + " Seconds"

}
```

Comment: Is there any minimum or maximum value for your slider?

Comment: Both minutes and seconds are set by the same slider.

Comment: The minimum value is 5, the maximum is 1800(which is 30 minutes), the current value set to 59.

Comment: Why don't you keep the value only in seconds and calculate the number of minutes only when needed? `label.text = "\(seconds / 60)  Minute: \(seconds % 60) Seconds"`

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the logic of changing seconds to minutes and use this code -

```
var dateFormatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
dateFormatter.allowedUnits = ([.minute, .second])
dateFormatter.unitsStyle = .full
label1.text = dateFormatter.string(from: 105)
```

Output -

1 minute, 45 seconds

Answer (score 0):

From the code, you gave my guess is that this line is redundant:

```
minute = Int(sender.value)
```

Consider removing it.

Btw, what exactly won't work? What's the current behavior?

Comment: the 'label.text = String(minute) + " Minute :" + String(seconds) + " Seconds" ' will be out put like this: 1800 Minute : 1800 Seconds. Btw, The minimum value is 5, the maximum is 1800(which is 30 minutes), the current value set is 59.

Comment: consider removing `minute = Int(sender.value)` cuz you are setting seconds into the minutes for some reason

Answer (score 0):

Just Changed Your logic as:

```
    @IBAction func slider(sender: UISlider) {

    seconds = Int(sender.value)

    minute = seconds/60

    label.text = String(minute) + " Minute :" + String(seconds-(minute*60)) + " Seconds"

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
@IBAction func slider(sender: UISlider) {

let currentSec = Int(sender.value)
minute = currentSec/60
seconds = currentSec%60

label.text = String(minute) + " Minute :" + String(seconds) + " Seconds"

}
```